# Ik rotation Deformation Problem

Tags: rigging

I am trying to use inverse kinematics but for the bone would not bend in the right direction so i tried rolling it but the it deformed the foot and leg of the mesh how do i fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload your .blend file to be able to help you

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Use this link http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have uploaded the file

Comment: I've provided an answer to your problem with steps and an updated blend file. You can accept the answer and upvote the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of problems in your file.

First the IK bones needs to have the deform property disabled as shown below:

[image]

Second, you need to adjust the pose position to be your rest pose to avoid bad bone roll values. To do this, switch to pose mode select the whole armature bones by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> then hit the space bar and write `Apply Pose as Rest Pose` as shown below:

[image]

Last thing is parenting your mesh to your armature. To do this, go to object mode, select your mesh first, then select your armature with right-click, then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `With Automatic Weight` and that's it, the mesh will be nicely deformed and parented to the armature as shown below:

[image]

The updated .blend file can be found here: [image]